# R - split based on singel delimiter criteria, to create multiple lists

Tags: r

Good Morning,

I am relatively new with R, and the following question has me stymied since yesterday.

I'm working on a list of following format:

```
 X
                      t          Ph       Ti        Te     Delta
2   2014-02-16 05:00:00    0.000000 19.83400  4.392333 15.441667
3   2014-02-16 10:00:00   24.997867 20.22083  7.637000 12.583833
4   2014-02-16 15:00:00 2349.799467 22.73400  7.735500 14.998500
5   2014-02-16 20:00:00    0.000000 23.66300  4.917167 18.745833
6   2014-02-17 01:00:00    0.000000 21.99467  3.810167 18.184500
7   2014-02-17 06:00:00    0.000000 20.35433  4.665167 15.689167
8   2014-02-17 11:00:00   15.907733 20.18267  8.206167 11.976500
9   2014-02-17 16:00:00 2542.964800 22.33983  8.385833 13.954000
```

...

What I'm trying to do is to divide this list based on the "Delta" value, in such a way as to separate the rows where the delta value is over 15 from the rest, like this:

```
 X2
$`1`
                    t       Ph       Ti       Te    Delta
2 2014-02-16 05:00:00  0.00000 19.83400 4.392333 15.44167

$`2`
                    t       Ph     Ti     Te   Delta
3 2014-02-16 10:00:00 24.99787 20.22083 7.637000 12.58383
4 2014-02-16 15:00:00 2349.799 22.734 7.7355 14.9985

$`3`
                    t       Ph       Ti       Te    Delta
5 2014-02-16 20:00:00  0.00000 23.66300 4.917167 18.74583
6 2014-02-17 01:00:00  0.00000 21.99467 3.810167 18.18450
7 2014-02-17 06:00:00  0.00000 20.35433 4.665167 15.68917

$`4`
                    t       Ph       Ti       Te  Delta
8 2014-02-17 11:00:00 15.90773 20.18267 8.206167 11.97650
9 2014-02-17 16:00:00 2542.965 22.33983 8.385833 13.954

$`5`
                     t       Ph      Ti       Te    Delta
10 2014-02-17 21:00:00 15.90773 23.0335 7.994833 15.03867
```

I have found this bit of code on the internet:

```
X2<-split(X, cumsum(DeltaT < 15)))
```

which gives folowing result :

```
 X2
$`0`
                    t Ph     Ti       Te    Delta
2 2014-02-16 05:00:00  0 19.834 4.392333 15.44167

$`1`
                    t       Ph       Ti    Te    Delta
3 2014-02-16 10:00:00 24.99787 20.22083 7.637 12.58383

$`2`
                    t       Ph       Ti       Te    Delta
4 2014-02-16 15:00:00 2349.799 22.73400 7.735500 14.99850
5 2014-02-16 20:00:00    0.000 23.66300 4.917167 18.74583
6 2014-02-17 01:00:00    0.000 21.99467 3.810167 18.18450
7 2014-02-17 06:00:00    0.000 20.35433 4.665167 15.68917

$`3`
                    t       Ph       Ti       Te   Delta
8 2014-02-17 11:00:00 15.90773 20.18267 8.206167 11.9765

$`4`
                     t         Ph       Ti       Te    Delta
9  2014-02-17 16:00:00 2542.96480 22.33983 8.385833 13.95400
10 2014-02-17 21:00:00   15.90773 23.03350 7.994833 15.03867
```

As you can see, the use of cumsum means I always include the last row with Delta value under 15 into the blocks over 15. Is there an other way to acheive this result? Help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I am using data.table::rleid function (run length encoding) for this, Here df is your dataframe:

```
df$rle <- data.table::rleid(df$Delta < 15)
split(df, df$rle)
```

**Output:**

```
$`1`
  sn                t Ph     Ti       Te    Delta rle
1  2 16-02-2014 05:00  0 19.834 4.392333 15.44167   1

$`2`
  sn                t         Ph       Ti     Te    Delta rle
2  3 16-02-2014 10:00   24.99787 20.22083 7.6370 12.58383   2
3  4 16-02-2014 15:00 2349.79947 22.73400 7.7355 14.99850   2

$`3`
  sn                t Ph       Ti       Te    Delta rle
4  5 16-02-2014 20:00  0 23.66300 4.917167 18.74583   3
5  6 17-02-2014 01:00  0 21.99467 3.810167 18.18450   3
6  7 17-02-2014 06:00  0 20.35433 4.665167 15.68917   3

$`4`
  sn                t         Ph       Ti       Te   Delta rle
7  8 17-02-2014 11:00   15.90773 20.18267 8.206167 11.9765   4
8  9 17-02-2014 16:00 2542.96480 22.33983 8.385833 13.9540   4

$`5`
  sn                t       Ph      Ti       Te    Delta rle
9 10 17-02-2014 21:00 15.90773 23.0335 7.994833 15.03867   5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you show me how to remove the data frames  in which the delta value is superior to 15?

Comment: @K.DeSloover   `splitted <- split(df, df$rle);
just_filter <- function(x)x < 15;
lapply(splitted, function(x)Filter(just_filter, x$Delta));
` If I understood you correctly, also make sure you ask everything in your question, Please make sure you don't fall to an xy problem ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. However, I can't get your code to work. I don't get an error message or anything, the "splitted" list is just exactly the same as the one in the output above.

Comment: @K. De Sloover there are three lines of code , not sure what you are running, the last line which includes the Filter command is your answer, save it in some object.  `Output <- lapply(splitted, function(x)Filter(just_filter, x$Delta));` Make sure you have run the other two commands before it. Output would contain your final result

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we could use `rle`

```
split(X, with(rle(X$Delta > 15), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))
#$`1`
                    t Ph     Ti       Te    Delta
#2 2014-02-16 05:00:00  0 19.834 4.392333 15.44167

#$`2`
                    t         Ph       Ti     Te    Delta
#3 2014-02-16 10:00:00   24.99787 20.22083 7.6370 12.58383
#4 2014-02-16 15:00:00 2349.79947 22.73400 7.7355 14.99850

#$`3`
#                    t Ph       Ti       Te    Delta
#5 2014-02-16 20:00:00  0 23.66300 4.917167 18.74583
#6 2014-02-17 01:00:00  0 21.99467 3.810167 18.18450
#7 2014-02-17 06:00:00  0 20.35433 4.665167 15.68917

#$`4`
#                    t         Ph       Ti       Te   Delta
#8 2014-02-17 11:00:00   15.90773 20.18267 8.206167 11.9765
#9 2014-02-17 16:00:00 2542.96480 22.33983 8.385833 13.9540

#$`5`
                     t       Ph      Ti       Te    Delta
#10 2014-02-17 21:00:00 15.90773 23.0335 7.994833 15.03867
```

#### data

```
X <- structure(list(t = c("2014-02-16 05:00:00", "2014-02-16 10:00:00", 
"2014-02-16 15:00:00", "2014-02-16 20:00:00", "2014-02-17 01:00:00", 
"2014-02-17 06:00:00", "2014-02-17 11:00:00", "2014-02-17 16:00:00", 
"2014-02-17 21:00:00"), Ph = c(0, 24.997867, 2349.799467, 0, 
0, 0, 15.907733, 2542.9648, 15.90773), Ti = c(19.834, 20.22083, 
22.734, 23.663, 21.99467, 20.35433, 20.18267, 22.33983, 23.0335
), Te = c(4.392333, 7.637, 7.7355, 4.917167, 3.810167, 4.665167, 
8.206167, 8.385833, 7.994833), Delta = c(15.441667, 12.583833, 
14.9985, 18.745833, 18.1845, 15.689167, 11.9765, 13.954, 15.03867
)), .Names = c("t", "Ph", "Ti", "Te", "Delta"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```